# How do I compare the values gotten from html checkbox to id of same values in database?

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates, many-to-many

I am fairly new to Django and I use the 4.2 version. This is my problem. I am building a blog website, I was trying to add multiple values(tags) for each blog post, from the HTML template checkbox input to my database, which is PostgreSQL. In that database, I already have pre-stored values of items in a Tags table. This table has a ManyToMany relationship with the main Blogpost class. But I am having problems with this particular process. I am trying to add tags for each blogpost created, from the tags already set in the Tags table. The idea is that a user selects the tags they want to include in their blogpost and in the manytomany table, the ids of the tags and the blogpost are set, when the blogpost is saved. I understand that I am to get the id of the values I am trying to add from my database where they exist and include them in the blogpost but I don't exactly know how to do this.
This is what my code looks like:

**models.py**

```
class BlogPost(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, unique=True, primary_key='True', editable=False)
    post_title = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Title of blog post')
    post_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='posts/%Y/%m/%d', default='static/images/avatar.jpg', blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Blog post picture')
    tags = models.ManyToManyField('Tags', blank=True,  verbose_name='Tags seperated by #')



class Tags(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, unique=True, primary_key=True)
    tag = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

**views.py**

```
def loadCreatePostPage(request):
    # blogform = BlogForm()
    context = {
        'has_error': False,
        'data': request.POST,
    }
    
    if request.method == 'POST':
        title = request.POST['post_title']
        image = request.FILES.get('post_image')
        # image = request.FILES['post_image']
        add_tag = request.POST.getlist('genre')
        body = request.POST['post_body']
```

I have tried to loop through the queryset Tags, but for some reason unknown, the if statement is not giving expected results:

```
def loadCreatePostPage(request):
    # blogform = BlogForm()
    context = {
        'has_error': False,
        'data': request.POST,
    }
    
    if request.method == 'POST':
        title = request.POST['post_title']
        image = request.FILES.get('post_image')
        # image = request.FILES['post_image']
        add_tag = request.POST.getlist('genre')
        body = request.POST['post_body']

        print(title,image,add_tag)
        try:
            blog = BlogPost(post_title=title, post_image=image, post_body=body)
            # for tag in range(len(add_tag)):
            #     blog.tags.add(add_tag[tag])
            t_tags = Tags.objects.get(tag='fantasy')
            print(add_tag[0])
            if t_tags == (add_tag[0]):
                return True
            print(t_tags)
            # blog.tags_set.add()

            
            # blog.save()
            # all_tags = Tags.objects.all()
            # all_tags = list(all_tags)
            # for tag in range(len(all_tags)):
            #     # print(tag)
            #     pretag = all_tags[tag]
            #     for x in range(len(add_tag)):
            #         print(add_tag[x])
            #         if add_tag[x] in all_tags:
            #             print('yes')
            #         else:
            #             print('no')

                # print(pretag, type(pretag))
                
                
            # blog.save()
        except ValueError:
            print('Something is wrong')
        
    return render(request, 'blogpages/create.html', context)
```

I would appreciate some assistance and/or corrections, I am confused

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you are trying to do in your view as it seems to combine different approaches that you tried. But I think my solution solves your problem :)

**A few general hints:**

- in python, you don't need to loop through a list using an index number, like you try to do in `for tag in range(len(all_tags))`. Just use `for tag in all_tags` instead.
- you don't need to manually set an ID field in your models. Neither do you need to access the ID when working with objects from the database. That's what the django models are for - you interact with an instance of your model class and don't need to worry about database internals like IDs. Maybe this is where your confusion comes from.

**Solution:**

models.py (simplified):

```
class BlogPost(models.Model):
    post_title = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField('Tags')

class Tags(models.Model):
    tag = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

the template form (in create.html):

```
<form action="/create" method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <input type="text" name="title" />
            {% for t in tags %}
            <label for="{{ t.tag  }}">{{ t.tag }}</label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="{{ t.tag }}" name="tags" value="{{ t.tag }}" />
            {% endfor %}
            <button type="submit">Create post!</button>
        </form>
```

the view:

```
def create(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        # provide all existing tags to the template. This will be 
        # used to display a checkbox for each tag in the template
        tags = Tags.objects.all()
        return render(request, 'create.html', {'tags': tags})
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # create and save the new blog post without tags first
        new_post = BlogPost(post_title=request.POST['title'])
        new_post.save()
        # iterate through the selected tags
        for tag_name in request.POST.getlist('tags'):
            # get the corresponding object from the database
            tag = Tags.objects.get(tag=tag_name)
            # then add the database object to the new blogpost
            new_post.tags.add(tag)
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
```